# Do we say "to slide down with your legs going first" or "to slide down legs-first"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Ok, my little daughter likes going down the slide. But the problem is that sometimes she wants to slide down head-first like in this picture, which is very dangerous.

[image]

> [head-first](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/head-first), headfirst /ˌhedˈfɜːst◂ $ -ˈfɜːrst◂/ adverb
>
> 1 if you fall head-first, your head goes down first, and the rest of
>   your body follows afterwards
>
> dive/fall/jump/plunge head-first
>
> I fell head-first down the stairs.

---

I want her to slide down with her legs going first like this

[image]

So, what should I say?

**Sweetie, please slide down with your legs going first or please slide down legs-first**

Also, 
**what about other parts of the body going first such as "butt-first" or "hands- first", etc?**

Note: We have the adverb "**head-first**" but no "**legs-first**"

Answer (score 2):

Personally I have no problem with “legs first”, but you’re right (to my surprise) that it’s well-nigh impossible to find in use anywhere. I think the word you’re looking for is *feetfirst.* Google Ngram suggests it has been in use since at least 1965.

P.S. I’m not an expert, but I do have kids (now grown) and they went down their similarly-sized slide head-first, feet-first, face-first, you-name-it-first, and it never did them any harm.

Comment: also, what about other parts of the body like "butt-first" or "hands- first", etc?

Comment: @Tom *Feet First* or *Head First* are the usual idioms (BrE here). Bum/butt first would confuse me - unless you mean to go down facing *backwards* in the sitting position?